# How can I get the ID of the member who just joined the server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How can I get the ID of the member who just joined the server? Like, member just joined my server and I need to get his ID. How I can do this?

member.id doesn't work, as this gives:

> AttributeError: 'CachedSlotProperty' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/R09fQ3Sg
password: 123123

Comment: Code you want us to look at must be here, in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error not in `member.id`. It's in `str((discord.Message).guild.id)`. What were you trying to do with this? If you need to get ID of guild of member use `member.guild.id`.